# How to react the changes on localstorage by using computed property

Tags: vue.js

I am using a composition API to fetch the data from the localstorage.

I'm saving an array into local storage and adding/removing from the array like.

```
export function useCart() {
  const addToCart = (item) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
    basketItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basketArray")) || [];
    var newItem = {
      id: item.id,
      image: item.image,
      price: item.price,
      rating: item.rating,
      title: item.title,
    };
    basketItem.push(newItem);

    localStorage.setItem("basketArray", JSON.stringify(basketItem));
  };
```

I want the count of the array to update in the component as and when new items get added to the array in localstorage

I am using a computed property as:

```
import { computed } from "@vue/composition-api";
import { useCart } from "../../js/ShoppingCart";
// import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
export default {
  setup() {
    const { basketItem } = useCart();

    let basketLength = computed(
      () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basketArray"))?.length
    );

    return { basketLength, basketItem };
  },
  name: "Navbar",
  components: {},
};
```

The `length` is not changing as expected. it only loads at first and otherwise remains the same.

The goal is having the value react to the localstorage change while getting the value as `computed()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` is a disk storage solution, it won't be reactive magically. If you want `basketItems` to be reactive. Declare it as a `ref`:

```js
import { ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export function useCart() {
  const basketItems = ref([])
  const addToCart = (item) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
    basketItems.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basketArray")) || [];
    var newItem = {
      id: item.id,
      image: item.image,
      price: item.price,
      rating: item.rating,
      title: item.title,
    };
    basketItems.value.push(newItem);

    localStorage.setItem("basketArray", JSON.stringify(basketItems.value));
 };
 // remember to return basketItems here
 return { basketItems, addToCart }
}
```

Then in component setup:

```js
setup() {
  const { basketItems, addToCart } = useCart();
  const basketLength = computed(() => basketItems.value.length);
  return { basketItems, basketLength, addToCart }
}
```

Both `basketItems` and `basketLength` should be reactive here, and you can add item to car via the `addToCart` method.

Comment: does this will make the system reactive on the `cart` items changed or removed across all the devices, browser tabs? eventually, I want to move the local storage to some databases in the backend. What could be the possible workaround in that case?

Comment: I don't think it will be reactive across devices and tabs. It's meant to be reactive within a session. If you want to be reactive across devices / tabs, you need a database with subscription api. Maybe firebase or something similar.

Comment: I have got some problem here when I moved the `const basketItems = ref([]);
basketItems.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basketArray")) || [];` outside the `useCart()` to incorporate to load the item from localstorage in initial load. the count on `basketLength` is zero, but there are correct items in `basketItems`.

Comment: this `localStorage.setItem("basketArray", JSON.stringify(basketItems));` should be changed to stored the `basketItems.value`.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry missed that part :)